# If div has class remove class or else add a new class

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a '-' button on my WordPress website that I want to use to add a class to the `<body>` of my page to increase font size. I also have a '+' button, which will decrease the size of font.

Plus button HTML:
`<div class="biggerTextButton"><p>+</p></div>`

Minus button HTML:
`<div class="smallerTextButton"><p>-</p></div>`

In the stylesheet I have styles for 'biggerText' and 'smallerText'. What I want to avoid is having both these classes as a `<body>` class (hence I cannot just add/remove/toggle class.

How would I do this with jQuery? For the '-' button I've tried this, but it does not work.

```
    jQuery('smallerTextButton').click(function (){
        if ( jQuery('body').hasClass('biggerText')) {
            jQuery('body').removeClass('biggerText');
        } else {
            jQuery('body').addClass('smallerText');
        }
    });
});
```

I think I am incorrectly using if/else statements, but cannot see why it does not work. Obviously, the above text would online apply to clicking the 'smallerTextButton', but would I use the same solution for 'biggerTextButton', with appropriate classes? :)

Comment: You can use [.toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that your jQuery selector was missing the `.` prefix for the class.

With regard to your issue, the simplest way to achieve this would be to remove both classes from the `body` before you add the relevant one from the clicked `div`. All you need to do is add a 'normal size' option to enable users to revert the font size back to normal.

I would also suggest you change the trigger elements to buttons. As you're doing this for accessibility reasons, you should build the HTML to best standards for screen readers. They can still be styled to not look like buttons, if you prefer.

```js
let $body = $('body');

$('.textAmendmentButton').on('click', function() {
  $body.removeClass('biggerText smallerText').addClass(this.dataset.bodyclass);
});
```

```css
body { font-size: 1em; }
body.smallerText { font-size: 0.7em; }
body.biggerText { font-size: 2em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="textAmendmentButton" data-bodyclass="biggerText">+</button>
<button type="button" class="textAmendmentButton" data-bodyclass="">N</button>
<button type="button" class="textAmendmentButton" data-bodyclass="smallerText">-</button>

<h1>Foo bar</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipscing elit. </p>
```